# Change a value from a nested object using localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have this code that set the `obj` value in localstorage.

```js
const obj = {
  name: "Bill",
  meta: {
    age: 18
  }
};
const data = localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Now i want to change the `age` key in the localstorage:
`localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({ ...data, ...data.meta.age= 15 } }));`, but it does not work. 
How to change the value above and to see the changes in localstorage?

Comment: Do you not need to get the item and parse it before trying to change it?

Comment: What is `data` in your code that doesn't work? It should be the current version of your data (for instance, `const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));`).

Comment: `const newObj = obj; newObj.meta.age = 15; const data = localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(newObj));` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `data`, the problem is that `...data.meta.age = 15` is a syntax error. You don't use `=` in object literals, and it does't make sense to try to spread the `age` property (which is a number). Instead:

```
const newData = {
    ...data,
    meta: {
        ...data.meta,
        age: 15,
    },
};
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newData));
```

Notice how we have to create a new outermost object and also a new object for `meta`.

Live Example:

```js
const data = {
    name: "Bill",
    meta: {
        occupation: "Programmer", // Added so we see it get copied
        age: 18,
    },
};
const newData = {
    ...data,
    meta: {
        ...data.meta,
        age: 15,
    },
};
console.log(newData);
```